# spark selectExpr error in stack function with array types columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have this code:

```
    str_stack_query ="stack( 7,  'SERIAL_NO',SERIAL_NO  ,  'TICKET_NO',TICKET_NO  ,  'FIXED_ASSET',FIXED_ASSET  ,  'RETREAT',RETREAT  ,  'ARTICLE',ARTICLE  ,  'DESCRIPTION',DESCRIPTION  ,  'ctl_rid',ctl_rid ) as (COL_NAME, SOURCE_VALUE)"

    column_model_df = complete_tabular_df.selectExpr("id","asset_id","source_max_date",str_stack_query ).cache()
```

and i've got this error :

> AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'stack(7, 'SERIAL_NO', complete_tabular_df.`SERIAL_NO`, 'TICKET_NO', complete_tabular_df.`TICKET_NO`, 'FIXED_ASSET', complete_tabular_df.`FIXED_ASSET`, 'RETREAT', complete_tabular_df.`RETREAT`, 'ARTICLE', complete_tabular_df.`ARTICLE`, 'DESCRIPTION', complete_tabular_df.`DESCRIPTION`, 'ctl_rid', complete_tabular_df.`ctl_rid`)' due to data type mismatch: Argument 2 (string) != Argument 14 (array); line 1 pos 0;\n'Project [id#28823, asset_id#28804, source_max_date#28861L, stack(7, SERIAL_NO, SERIAL_NO#4551, TICKET_NO, TICKET_NO#28847, FIXED_ASSET, FIXED_ASSET#28848, RETREAT, RETREAT#28849, ARTICLE, ARTICLE#28850, DESCRIPTION, DESCRIPTION#28851, ctl_rid, ctl_rid#28852) AS ArrayBuffer(COL_NAME, SOURCE_VALUE)]\n+- SubqueryAlias `complete_tabular_df`\n   +- Union\n      :- Project [SERIAL_NO#4551, id#28823, asset_id#28804, col#28842.TICKET_NO AS TICKET_NO#28847, col#28842.FIXED_ASSET AS FIXED_ASSET#28848, col#28842.RETREAT AS RETREAT#28849, col#28842.ARTICLE AS ARTICLE#28850, col#28842.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION#28851, col#28842.ctl_rid AS ctl_rid#28852, col#28842.ctl_rfp AS ctl_rfp#28853, col#28842.ctl_ts AS ctl_ts#28854, col#28842.ctl_file_name AS ctl_file_name#28855, col#28842.ctl_tid AS ctl_tid#28856, col#28842.ctl_sid AS ctl_sid#28857, col#28842.ctl_file_date AS ctl_file_date#28858, col#28842.ctl_eid AS ctl_eid#28859, col#28842.no_counts AS no_counts#28860L, col#28842.source_max_date AS source_max_date#28861L]\n      :  +- Project [SERIAL_NO#4551, id#28823, asset_id#28804, col#28842]\n      :     +- Generate explode(arrays_zip(TICKET_NO#28359, FIXED_ASSET#28360, RETREAT#28361, ARTICLE#28362, DESCRIPTION#28363, ctl_rid#28364, ctl_rfp#28365, ctl_ts#28366, ctl_file_name#28367, ctl_tid#28368, ctl_sid#28369, ctl_file_date#28370, ctl_eid#28371, no_counts#28372, source_max_date#28373)), true, [col#28842]\n      :

the error is because this column : ctl_rid is of array type, and all the others are string type.
So, is there any other way to do it or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`array_join`** function to create a **string** from **array** then use in **`stack`** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+---+-----------+
#|sno| pp|    ctl_rid|
#+---+---+-----------+
#|  a|  b|[12, 34, 4]|
#+---+---+-----------+

str_stack_query ="stack(2,'sno',sno,'ctl_rid',array_join(ctl_rid,',')) as (COL_NAME,SOURCE_VALUE)"

df.selectExpr(str_stack_query).show()
#+--------+------------+
#|COL_NAME|SOURCE_VALUE|
#+--------+------------+
#|     sno|           a|
#| ctl_rid|     12,34,4|
#+--------+------------+

#incase if you want to show array in []
str_stack_query ="stack(2,'sno',sno,'ctl_rid',concat('[',array_join(ctl_rid,','),']')) as (COL_NAME,SOURCE_VALUE)"

df.selectExpr(str_stack_query).show()
#+--------+------------+
#|COL_NAME|SOURCE_VALUE|
#+--------+------------+
#|     sno|           a|
#| ctl_rid|   [12,34,4]|
#+--------+------------+
```